# How to hide Home/Index and show another view in its place

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a typical mvc application, and am running into an issue with hiding the Home/Index view and replacing it with a another view. 
What happens is a user logs in and the view that is rendered by @RenderBody() is Home/Index and has a grid on it that the user uses to start creating an order. On this page is also a Menu button. When the user selects Administration from the menu, I would like to hide the Home/Index view and show another view which is the Administration section which has a close button and when that close button is clicked that it will unload the Administration section and unhide the Home/Index view.

The Home/Index has to be hidden because if the user is the middle of creating an order then everything should still be there.

I have tried doing this with just using a modal popup, but it throws my Administration section layout off.

Screenshot 1, would be the Home/Index and I want to hide that and show Screenshot 2, and when the close button is clicked from Screenshot 2, Screenshot 2 should unload and Screenshot 1 should appear again.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

**EDIT**

The code in the _Layout partial view is

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div id="ShowAdminPartialView">
    </div>
    <div id="HideForAdminPartialView">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to hide the HideForAdminPartialView, and when I unhide the ShowAdminPartialView, I lose the top navigation bar, and I believe this to be because since I hide the HideForAdminPartialView div, that it also hides the @RenderBody() and I think thats why I lose the top nav bar

Comment: Hi, providing some code may help us help you

Comment: @Jaay, I'll do that right now..one sec..

Comment: Just an idea, can't you just hide and show different view groups in css?